# What is a good approach to ingest client sql data passively (client push) using Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Our client doesn't want to let us make any call in their SQL database (even create a replica, etc). The best solution we have thought until now is instantiating a Google Cloud SQL server, so we can ask customer to push its data once a day/week (using the public IP of the server) and then we consume the data pushing into Google Big Query.

I have been reading many topics on the web and my possible solution is asking user doing weekly ETL -> Cloud SQL -> BigQuery. Is it a good approach?

To sum up, I am looking for recommendations about **best/cheap** practices and possible ways to let the user insert data in GCP without exposing his data or my infrastructure.
My cloud provider is Google Cloud and my client uses SQL Server.
We are open to new or similar options (even other providers like Amazon and Azure)

Constraints:

Client will send data periodically (once a day/or week ingestion)
Data finally should be sent and stored in BigQuery
The costs of having a Cloud SQL in Google is high while we don't need the allocated CPU/Memory and public IP available 24/7 (only a few times a month, e.g: 4 times a month)

Comment: Your question is low on details and that makes a good answer difficult. 1) Is there anything stored in the database that is a problem to import into BigQuery? 2) The simplest method is to query the SQL database on date or id, process each row and then import directly into BigQuery (or a BQ temp table for later merge). Repeat on a schedule.

Comment: Is google cloud SQL Server an actual requirement of this or are you just throwing random technology at a basic data replication problem? The simplest solution for you is to just copy their nightly backups and restore them into a SQL Server... somewhere.... doesn't have to be google, doesn't have to be cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing many details, but how about:

- Have the customer create a weekly .csv.
- Send the .csv with the new data to GCS.
- Load into BigQuery.